Why is the dimension of this region 1?
Why is the dimension of this region 1? I thought the intersection is just one point, so the expected dimension should be 0. 
(14.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)) 
It seems like the same bug in previous version here.
points = {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 0}, {0, 0}};
polygon = RegionConvert[Polygon@Rationalize@points, "Implicit"];
line = ConditionalExpression[-2 + 3 x, x >= 1] /. 
   ConditionalExpression[yval_, dom_] :> 
    ImplicitRegion[Rationalize[y == yval && dom], {x, y}];
RegionDimension[RegionIntersection[polygon, line]]



This bug introduced in v12.3.
Since RegionConvert not in version 11.3 and 12.2, we use RegionMember instead.

$Version
points = {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 0}, {0, 0}};
polygon2 = 
  ImplicitRegion[
   Simplify[
    RegionMember[Polygon@points]@{x, y}, {x, y} ∈ Reals], {x,
     y}];
line = ConditionalExpression[-2 + 3 x, x >= 1] /. 
   ConditionalExpression[yval_, dom_] :> 
    ImplicitRegion[Rationalize[y == yval && dom], {x, y}];
RegionDimension[RegionIntersection[polygon2, line]]



We have to use Reduce.

reg = ImplicitRegion[
   Reduce[{x, y} ∈ RegionIntersection[polygon, line], {x, 
     y}], {x, y}];
reg // RegionDimension
reg // RegionMeasure[#, 1] &


0.


0.

